# Typescript - Interfaces and extending them in type assertion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I am having a little bit of problem of understanding the code down below. I do understand what type assertion is in Typescript, and what `extends` means, and what the functionality of that word is, but in this case I am confused why it has been used in this way. Basically, I want to use `react-hook-form` in Typescript, and I found out on their website similiar code, which I just rewrote so I can use it my own way. This code works, but I am not quite sure that I understand it?

#### Code

```
import { useForm, FieldValues, UseFormProps, UseFormSetValue } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { AnyObjectSchema } from 'yup';

interface OptionsForForm<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TContext extends object = object,
> extends UseFormProps<TFieldValues, TContext> {
  schema?: AnyObjectSchema | undefined;
}
```

What is the meaning of this code?

```
OptionsForForm<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TContext extends object = object,
>
```

I created the interface with the name `OptionsForForm` and on the official page it is showing that I need to do the **Type Assertion** (what is inside the angle brackets). But why `TFieldValues` extends the `FieldValues` and then we write `= FieldValues`.

I am confused by this, so if anyone can help me with explaining this part of the code, I would gladly appreciate it!

Comment: You don't have any type assertions here, all of the `<>` are for generic types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html.

Comment: Those are generic types, not type assertions. `TFieldsValue` is a generic type that `extends FieldValues` and `= FieldValues` is it's default type.

Comment: Ouh, well then I did not understand that also. So we are extending the generic types, correct?